# Knowledge Graph API in BigQuery

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, freebase, google-knowledge-graph

Is there a dump of the Knowledge Graph API on BigQuery or can I query Knowledge graph API via BigQuery SQL language?

[Felipe has this wonderful talk on querying Freebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lV5vk3higvA) via SQL but Freebase is no more updated.

Any chance I can do the equivalent of what Felippe does with Freebase and Wikidata with the Knowledge Graph API?

Answer (score 2):

As the Knowledge Graph Search API returns only [individual matching entities](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/#sample_request) I recommend to use the [wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page) dump, the fh-bigquery:wikidata dataset is available in BigQuery. You can run a statement like:

```
SELECT id FROM [fh-bigquery:wikidata.latest_en_v1] LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: is the statement for big-query or for wikidata query (sparql) ?

Comment: For BigQuery, you can try it in the WebUI